# Matrix elementary operation switch signs of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a way to switch specific elements of a matrix thru matrix multiplication, from left or right, and by one matrix or multiple.

Just as example (the size and the elements may differ) : 
How to switch the elements of the matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to get :
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&2&-3\\
4&-5&6\\
7&8&9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
There is the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), but it doesn't allow to calculate the determinant of the product from the determinants of the two (or more) other matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the $ 2 \times 2$ case. You'd like to have
$$
\pmatrix{p & q \\ r & s}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} = \pmatrix{a & -b \\ c & d}
$$
for a fixed $p, q, r, s$ and all $a, b, c, d$. So 
$$
pa + qc = a
$$
for all $a, c$, which says that (by picking $c = 0$ and $a = 1$) that $p = 1$ and $q = 0$. Similarly, 
$$
rb + sd = d
$$
tells us that $r  = 0$ and $s = 1$. But in this case, the left matrix is the identity, so the condition on $b$ is not met.

Short summary: flipping the sign of $b$ cannot be done merely by left multiplication. Perhaps, though, it can be done by a combination of left and right multiplication. Let's suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that it can be done by matrices $P$ and $T$. Then we'd have
$$
P A T = A',
$$
where $A'$ denotes the matrix $A$ with its upper right entry negated, for every matrix $A$. Plugging in $A = I$, we see that $T$ must be $P^{-1}$, hence $P$ and $T$ are invertible. Hence we must have
$$
P A P^{-1}= A'
$$
for every matrix $A$, i.e., 
$$
PA = A' P
$$
for every matrix $A$. Writing that out in individual entries, we have
$$
\pmatrix{p & q \\ r & s}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}  = \pmatrix{a & -b \\ c & d}\pmatrix{s & -q \\ -r & p}
$$
for every $a, b, c, d$. Picking $a = 1, b = c= d = 0$, we find from the upper left entry that $pa = as$, and since $a = 1$, this says that $p = s$. So now we have
$$
\pmatrix{p & q \\ r & p}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}  = \pmatrix{a & -b \\ c & d}\pmatrix{p & -q \\ -r & p}
$$
Looking at the $1,1$ entry of the two sides, we have
$$
pb + qd = -aq - bp
$$
for every $a, b, c, d$. Again, setting $a = 1, b = c = d = 0$, we get
$$
0 = -q
$$
hence $q = 0$. Setting $b = 1, a = c = d = 0$ gives $p = 0$. But now we'd have to have
$$
P = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ r & 0}
$$
which is not invertible. That's a contradiction.

In short: even in the $2 \times 2$ case, there's no left-and-right matrix multiplication that flips the sign of the $(1,1)$ entry of an arbitrary matrix.

Comment: totally agree for the arbitrary case, but if A is invertible, since $$A X = A'$$ can we take $$X = A^{-1} A'$$ but now we have an A-dependant solution

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But if $A$ is invertible, and $B$ is any other matrix, you can always "change $A$ to $B$" by postmultiplying by $A^{-1}B$; I'm not sure why this would be interesting, but I'm sure you have a good reason.